# Shiny update a table with an action button

Tags: r, shiny

Here is the relevant code for my Shiny App. Let me know if any additional code is needed. I am able to use the same method to render a plot but I am running into an error when trying to render a table.

**UI:**

```
actionButton("do", "Test!"),

fluidPage(
      tableOutput('table1')
),
```

**Server**

```
   globals <- reactiveValues(
    mydf = dat
   )

   count <- eventReactive(input$do, {  
    filter_mk <- input$mk
    filter_date <- input$date
    filter_universe <- input$universe

    dat_f <- globals$mydf %>% filter(date >= filter_date & universe %in% filter_universe & mrkcp_buckets %in% filter_mk)

    count <- dat_f %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      count()  %>%
      rename(st = n) %>%
      group_by(strftime(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
      filter(date == max(date)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(`strftime(date, \"%Y-%m\")`, st) %>%
      spread(`strftime(date, \"%Y-%m\")`, st)  %>%
      .[seq(1, length(.), 3)]

})

output$table1 <- renderTable({
  count()
}, caption= "Test",
caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top")
)
```

However, when I press the "Test" button, I am getting the following error: Error in count: unused argument (.). Wondering if I am missing something simple.

I also can not do `observeEvent(input$do, {output$table2 <- renderTable({.})` do to some other constraints that I did not show as an attempt at brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you have to specify the package when calling the `count` function, as R might confuse it with your reactive count-object.

A full working example would be this (I hope its close-enough to yours, but as you didnt provide a full minimum-working example, I had to make some guesses):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
   actionButton("do", "Test!"),
   # as a substitute for mk etc
   numericInput("numbers", "Max Group_n", min = 1, max = 1000, value = 100)
  ),
  tableOutput('table1')
 )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
 library(dplyr)

 globals <- reactiveValues(
  mydf = data.frame(x = 1:1000,
                    y = rnorm(1000),
                    group = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1000, T))
 )

 count <- eventReactive(input$do, {  
  filter_n <- input$numbers

  dat_f <- globals$mydf

  count <- dat_f %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   # make sure that we use dplyr's count and not the reactive count...
   dplyr::count() %>% 
   filter(n >= filter_n)

 })


 output$table1 <- renderTable({
  count()
 }, caption = "Test", caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Does that work for you?