# How to update datatable on click of actionButton?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

So I have a datatable in Shiny that I only want to update when the user changes the input parameters and clicks a button. Below is a minimum reproducible example of it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3, numericInput("num1", "Limiter1", value = 0)),
    column(3, numericInput("num2", "Limiter2", value = 0))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,actionButton("button1", "Apply filters1")),
    column(3,actionButton("button2", "Apply filters2"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(6,dataTableOutput("testtable1")),
    column(6,dataTableOutput("testtable2"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filteredData1 <- reactive({
    req(input$num1)
    iris %>%
      filter(Petal.Length >= input$num1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "num2", value = input$num1)

    output$testtable1 <- renderDataTable(datatable(filteredData1()))
  })

  filteredData2 <- reactive({
    req(input$num2)
    iris %>%
      filter(Petal.Length >= input$num2)
  })

  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    output$testtable2 <- renderDataTable(datatable(filteredData2()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Unfortunately, in this case, the datatable first loads when the user clicks the button but after that automatically updates every time the `input$num1` changes regardless of whether `button1` is clicked. Is there a way to update the table with the new parameters only when `button1` is clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shiny update a table with an action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524713/shiny-update-a-table-with-an-action-button)

Answer (score 1):

With a reactive value:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    numericInput("num1", "Limiter", value = 0)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    actionButton("button1", "Apply filters")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    dataTableOutput("testtable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filteredData <- reactiveVal(iris)
  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    filteredData(iris %>% filter(Petal.Length >= input$num1))
  })

  output$testtable <- renderDataTable(datatable(filteredData()))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This seems to be the way I need to implement it! Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @AnirudhNambiar Take a look at the doc (`?reactiveVal`), it is nice.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is this simple you can just change the `actionButton` for a `submitButton`

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    numericInput("num1", "Limiter", value = 0)
    ),
  fluidRow(
    submitButton("button1", "Apply filters")
    ),
  fluidRow(
    dataTableOutput("testtable")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filteredData <- reactive({
    req(input$num1)
    iris %>%
      filter(Petal.Length >= input$num1)
  })

  output$testtable <- renderDataTable(datatable(filteredData()))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I've updated the code since it wasn't as simple as I thought. Essentially, the flow that I would want here is:

Change `num1` -> click `button1` to update `testtable1` and `num2` -> click `button2` to update `testtable2`.